# aws pinpoint push notifications click not working

Tags: android, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, push, aws-pinpoint

I try to add push notifications feature to my app using Pinpoint, but I have an issue : the push notif is showing but there is no action when I click on it.
I receive my notifications on a Service. I build my notification like this :

```
val notifDetail =  NotificationDetails.builder()
                .from(message.from)
                .mapData(data)
                .intentAction(NotificationClient.FCM_INTENT_ACTION)
                .build()
```

And then I use handleCampaignPush to show the push :

```
notifClient.handleCampaignPush(notifDetail)
```

I tried to play with the parameter .intent on the NotificationsDetails Builder, but with no results :(

Someone has an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried using [`click_action`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)?

Comment: There isn't suck kind of option in PinPoint, but thx !

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your manifest file:

```
      <receiver
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.pinpoint.targeting.notification.PinpointNotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.amazonaws.intent.baidu.NOTIFICATION_OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add code to handle to react to incoming push notifications.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver notificationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Received notification from local broadcast. Display it in a dialog.");

        Bundle data = intent.getBundleExtra(PushListenerService.INTENT_SNS_NOTIFICATION_DATA);
        String message = PushListenerService.getMessage(data);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Push notification")
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .show();
    }
};
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-push-notifications.html